# IotEdge Invoke a method from a device to the hub

Tags: java, iot, azure-iot-hub

This way I invoke the methods, from the hub on a device and it works fine.

```
 DeviceMethod methodClient = DeviceMethod.createFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
 payload = ...
 String methodName = "insertUser"; 
 result = methodClient.invoke(deviceId, methodName, responseTimeout, connectTimeout, payload);
```

How can I invoke a method from the device to the hub? (device -> hub)

As deviceId is mandatory, what values shall I put?
result = methodClient.invoke(**deviceId**, methodName, responseTimeout, connectTimeout, payload);

I am using these 2 Java libraries

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
                <artifactId>iot-device-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
                <artifactId>iot-service-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct Methods are used when you want to invoke a specific function on your Device from the Service Side.

From the definition in [Understand and invoke direct methods from IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods)

> IoT Hub gives you the ability to invoke direct methods on devices **from the cloud**. Direct methods represent a request-reply interaction with a device similar to an HTTP call in that they succeed or fail immediately (after a user-specified timeout). This approach is useful for scenarios where the course of immediate action is different depending on whether the device was able to respond.

Therefore it is not intended that you call a direct method from the device itself.